# TALEND: Network error IOException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: database, database-connection, talend

I can connect to my database with SQL Manager Studio but when I am trying to establish a DB connection with TALEND the connection doesn't happen. I get:

```
Echec de la connexion Vous devez modifier les paramètres de la base de données.
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Échec de l'ouverture de session de l'utilisateur 'dwh_user'.
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:164)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataUtils.connect(ExtractMetaDataUtils.java:1054)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.testConnection(ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.java:311)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.utils.ManagerConnection.check(ManagerConnection.java:272)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm$26.runWithCancel(DatabaseForm.java:2335)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm$26.runWithCancel(DatabaseForm.java:1)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.dialog.AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel$1.runnableWithCancel(AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel.java:77)
      at org.talend.repository.ui.dialog.AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel$ARunnableWithProgressCancel$1.call(AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel.java:161)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Échec de l'ouverture de session de l'utilisateur 'dwh_user'.
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:603)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:345)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.DriverShim.connect(DriverShim.java:41)
      at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:155)
      ... 9 more
```

Comment: can you add details like what component you are using in talend and what properties are you entering in your input component..like port, name etc..?

Answer (score 0):

Did you place JDBC driver for the database if not check whether you have placed JDBC driver or not, other than that also check port number.